# Global variables not working on excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use global variables in a excel macro I'm creating, but i can't get them to work. I wrote te following code:

```
Public globalVar As Integer

Public Sub TestGlobal()
    SetGlobalVar

    GetGlobalVar
End Sub

Public Sub SetGlobalVar()
    globalVar = 5
End Sub

Public Sub GetGlobalVar()
    Debug.Print "globalVar = "
    Debug.Print globalVar
End Sub
```

I expected this code to show `globalVar = 5`, but it's showing `globalVar =`, and when I put the mouse over the `globalVar` variable in `SetGlobalVar` it shows "5", but when I do that on `GetGlobalVar`, it shows "Empty".

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the value be the same, since the variable is global?

Comment: Running TestGlobal here prints `globalVar =` then `5` on the next line as expected.  Right click globalVar in the declaration line and *add watch* then you can debug line by line and see how its value is changing.

Comment: Why not simply `Debug.Print "globalVar = " & globalVar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i run the code it works, just to check you are declaring the public variable at the top of the module and not after another sub?

Comment: Thats exactly it. I've already changed to 'Debug.Print "globalVar = " & globalVar', and it continued to show empty. But when i moved the global variable declaration to the top of the file it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Your *Immediate Window* may not be high enough.

Based on Coleman's suggestion:

[image]

Comment: That is a very good guess as to the source of OP's confusion. Since the code is so straightforward and works as expected, I couldn't figure out why he thought that there was a problem.